# Repeated authentication screen when using username and password

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm writing a connector to Datastudio and I decided to go for username and password authentication. My isAuthValid, setCredentials and getAuthType functions:

```
var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();

function isAuthValid() {
  const properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  const username = properties.getProperty('dscc.username');
  const password = properties.getProperty('dscc.password');
  console.log(username);
  console.log(password);
  return !!(username && password);
}

function setCredentials(request) {
  const isCredentialsValid = !!(request.userPass.username && request.userPass.password);
  console.log('username: ' + request.userPass.username);
  console.log('password: ' + request.userPass.password);
  if (!isCredentialsValid) {
    return {
      errorCode: "INVALID_CREDENTIALS"
    };
  }
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
    .setProperty('dscc.username', request.userPass.username)
    .setProperty('dscc.password', request.userPass.password);
  return {
    errorCode: "NONE"
  };
};

function getAuthType() {
  return cc.newAuthTypeResponse()
    .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.USER_PASS)
    .build();
}

function resetAuth() {
  const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.username');
  userProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.password');
}
```

It works, but almost always after the first attempt the login password screen reappears.

In the logs I can see that setCredentials is called with proper arguments and then isAuthValid with username and password equal to null. After the second attempt isAuthValid is called properly with expected arguments.

Does anyone have an idea why does it behave like this?

Comment: Sounds weird. Have you implemented resetAuth()? I noticed some inconsistent behaviors when I do not implement all required functions.

Comment: As you can see in the code sample I did implement it.
The worst thing is that this problem is nondeterministic and now I have troubles to verify whether it still happens or not.

Comment: Ouch, sorry. I didn't scroll your code (my fault). Anyway, maybe this was an old bug from DataStudio.